# ratchet push.js with phonegap (cordova)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ratchet-bootstrap, push.js

I use Ratchet. My phonegap app has two pages, containing jquery.js, ratchet.js, and blockui.js (jQuery-based).

index.html:

```
<script>$.blockUi()</script>
<a href="2.html" data-transition="slide-in">2.html</a>
```

2.html:

```
<a href="index.html" data-transition="slide-out">index.html</a>
```

at first `$.blockUi()` runs correctly. then I press the link at the first page. After I press the link on the second page, no JavaScript runs. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/twbs/ratchet#troubleshooting) on Github:

> Script tags containing JavaScript will not be executed on pages that
>   are loaded with push.js. If you would like to attach event handlers to
>   elements on other pages, document-level event delegation is a common
>   solution.

From the [docs site](http://goratchet.com/components/#push)

> Push.js binds an event to the document that returns a detail object
>   and can be used to fire a callback.

Therefore I believe you would have to use this event listener to get your scripts to run: 
`window.addEventListener('push', myFunction);`